# Why is there a type mismatch when unioning a collection of Datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get the `union` of an `ArrayBuffer[Dataset[_]]`.

So I wrote the the following code:

```
var buffer: ArrayBuffer[Dataset[_]] = ArrayBuffer.empty[Dataset[_]]

var size:Long = 0 
...

if size < 1000 {
  buffer.append(df)
  size = size + df.count()
} else {
  val unionedDataset = buffer.reduce(_ union _)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_$2(in value $anonfun)] where type _$2(in value $anonfun)
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_$2(in variable buffer)]
[error]           val unionedDataset = buffer.reduce(_ union _)
[error]                                                      ^
```

Shouldn't the type of the second argument in the anonymous function be the same type of the object at the index that was referenced?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I can avoid this issue by doing the following:

```
val unionedDataset = buffer.reduce(_.toDF() union _.toDF())
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayBuffer[Dataset[_]]` can contain e.g. a `Dataset[String]` and a `Dataset[Int]` at the same time, and `union` isn't defined for them.

If you had `ArrayBuffer[Dataset[T]] forSome { type T }`, you could write `buffer.reduce(_ union _)` but then `buffer.append(df)` won't work: `df` must have type `Dataset[T]` but you don't know what `T` is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Any` instead of `_`, this should also work:

```
var buffer: ArrayBuffer[Dataset[Any]] = ArrayBuffer.empty[Dataset[Any]]

var size:Long = 0 
...

if size < 1000 {
  buffer.append(df.asInstanceOf[Dataset[Any]])
  size = size + df.count()
} else {
  val unionedDataset = buffer.reduce(_ union _)
}
```